How may I free memory allocated by foreign C calls in Python?
TlDr: my Python code makes external C library calls. Internally, the Python scripts use a few hundred Mb of RAM but the external C calls are using many Gb, even when I no longer need the data they have outputted. I would like to know how to free this memory in Python - I don't fully understand how Python memory works, since everything is some kind of virtual variable, and gc.collect() possibly does nothing here since the memory was created by a C library and not Python code.

I've recently noticed my project - which is developed exclusively in Python 3.12, as of right now, and builds on top of Sagemath - uses an absurd amount of memory and have debugged it using tracemalloc and the resource library as indicated here. Nothing fancy, I more or less copied the display features from that answer into my own code.
I observe tracemalloc thinks I am using on the order of 300Mb of RAM whereas resource.getrusage thinks I am using 2300Mb of RAM. Task manager shows a bloated figure of 6Gb, though I'm sure that's mostly due to the fact I'm running on top of the WSL virtual machine. I'm almost certain the discrepancy of 2Gb between resource.getrusage and tracemalloc is due to Sagemath calling from external C libraries, such as libgap, during runtime. I obviously want this 2Gb of memory to be freed, since when I use slightly larger input sizes my program occupies some 10Gb of RAM and crashes WSL.
The code looks roughly like this:
for r in range(1, n):
   # initialise variables, load some references
   # import tracemalloc, resource, define a function to display memory usage
   G = self.groups[r]

   tracemalloc.start()

   for N, word in enumerate(huge_data_set):
       if N % threshold == 0:
          display_memory_usage()
       
       # do some stuff
       generators = ...
       
       stab = frozenset(G.subgroup(generators))
       self.stabiliser_lookup.update({(word, otherdata) : (stab, moredata)})

       # do similar things, occasionally calling Sage group creation
       # or group element creation functions

       perm_indices = ...
       self.permutation_lookup.update({(word, otherdata) : G(perm_indices)})

       # all of this is inside more nested for loops, omitted for readability

Tracemalloc indicates that my own, "personal" Python code is using very little memory. On an example where the program as a whole used 2.3Gb, it claimed the top usage in lines in /home/user/main.py was 30Mb. The greatest offender was /sage/perm_gps/permgroup.py which allegedly used 80Mb, but that's still nothing compared to 2.3Gb. I can only conclude tracemalloc doesn't detect external C library memory usage. However, please note I don't take the group object G.subgroup(generators), no: I bake it into a Python set, wanting only an immutable list of elements, elements which may be identified with elements of the precomputed self.groups attribute, and therefore any extra bloat caused by GAP should surely be unnecessary. All the data I need is explicitly referenced in my Python script and the line stab = frozenset(G.subgroup(generators)) reportedly uses a measly 17Mb of RAM.
How can I free up this extra 2Gb?
Ideally, there should be some way whereby frozenset is replaced with something that definitively caches the memory and frees up all other references to that variable, but I wouldn't know how to do that. I realise frozenset probably does quite little because, whatever, everything is virtual (my ignorance should be clear, hence the question).
